# iText7 don't work when I use CSS3 function target-counter in property content

Tags: css, spring-boot, itext, thymeleaf, html2pdf

I am very new to iText7. I am trying to create a pdf from a dynamic HTML string. So far I have been able to create the pdf using HtmlConverter.ConvertToPdf(). But the problem is that I need have a table of contents with chapters and page numbers at begin of the document. To do that, I wrote in my CSS file:

```
@page {
  margin: 40mm 17mm 17mm 17mm;
  size: A4 portrait;
  @top-center { 
    content: element(header); 
    width: 100%;
  }
  @bottom-right-corner {
    content: counter(page);
  }
}

a::after { 
  content: leader('.') target-counter(attr(href), page) 
}
```

And I wrote in my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Good Thymes Virtual Grocery</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{${baseUrl} + '/static/css/relatorio_fiscalizacao.css'}"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>ÍNDICE</h1>
  <ul style="page-break-after: always;">
    <li><a href="#ch1">STAFF</a></li>
    <li><a href="#ch2">OPERATION DATA</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h1 id="ch1" class="chapter">STAFF</h1>
  <p style="page-break-after: always;">....</p>

  <h1 id="ch3" class="chapter">OPERATION DATA</h1>
  <p style="page-break-after: always;">....</p>

</body>
</html>
```

And finally, I have a component in my Spring Boot application:

```
@Component
public class PdfGeneratorUtil {
@Autowired
private TemplateEngine templateEngine;

@Autowired
ServletContext servletContext;

@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

@Value("${baseUrl}")
private String baseUrl;

public ByteArrayOutputStream createPdf(String templateName, Map<String, Object> map, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(templateName, "The templateName can not be null");

    System.out.println(baseUrl);

    map.put("baseUrl", baseUrl);

    IWebContext ctx = new SpringWebContext(request, response, servletContext, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale(), map, context);


    String processedHtml = templateEngine.process(templateName, ctx);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(processedHtml, os, converterProperties);
        System.out.println("PDF created successfully");
    }
    finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { /*ignore*/ }
        }
    }

    return os;
    }
}
```

iText converts to Pdf fine. But the chapters from table of contens come up without the number of pages. And Log returns **"Content property target-counter is either invalid or uses unsupported function."**

I saw the file [CssContentPropertyResolver.java](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/com.itextpdf/html2pdf/2.1.1/source-code/com/itextpdf/html2pdf/css/resolve/CssContentPropertyResolver.java) and I realized that the code not treat the CSS function "target-counter". So, my question is: There is an other way to do that, maybe creating custom CSS appliers like [**this tutorial**](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-5-custom-tag-workers-and-css-appliers)? Or maybe other way? If not, anybody know any other library that I could use instead iTextPdf?

Comment: Can you please share the GitHub link to the code? It will be really easy to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Did you get any solution Even I have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

This works with recent versions of the html2pdf library - certainly 3.0.3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, only with the `leader()` function, which makes the line invalid. Try and remove the leader() and see if you get the page numbers. I'm trying to find another way to create the leading dots.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).